# ZF2 DB Adapter - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I'm using ZF2 DB Adapter and get following error on my query:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '"product"'

But "product" is no column, it's a value, so how come?

This is how I build the query:

```
$select = $this->getGateway()->getSql()->select();
$select->join('keywordlink', 'keywordlink_ref_type = "product" AND keywordlink_ref_id = product_id', ['keyword_count' => new Expression('COUNT(keyword_id)')], Select::JOIN_LEFT);
$select->where(['product_deleted IS NULL']);
$select->group(['product_id']);
```

Btw, the field keywordlink_ref_id is an ENUM in the mysql database.

When I write the SQL myself it works:

```
SELECT 
    product.*, COUNT(DISTINCT keywordlink_keyword_id) AS keyword_count
FROM
    adcheck.product
LEFT JOIN
    keywordlink
ON
    keywordlink_ref_type = "product" AND keywordlink_ref_id = product_id
WHERE
    product_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    product_id
```

Thanks

Comment: and what gives you `echo $select->getSqlString();` ?

Comment: what @venca said + try moving `keywordlink_ref_type = "product"` from the join to the `where` condition and see if it'll work.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but shouldn't it also work as it shows above?

Comment: $select->getSqlString() brings: SELECT "product".*, COUNT(DISTINCT keywordlink_keyword_id) AS "keyword_count" FROM "product" LEFT JOIN "keywordlink" ON "keywordlink_ref_type" = "\"""product""\"" AND "keywordlink_ref_id" = "product_id" WHERE product_deleted IS NULL GROUP BY "product_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't know why it didn't work as before but it works when I move the

> keywordlink_ref_type = "product"

into the where condition:

```
SELECT 
    product.*, COUNT(DISTINCT keywordlink_keyword_id) AS keyword_count
FROM
    adcheck.product
LEFT JOIN
    keywordlink
ON
    keywordlink_ref_id = product_id
WHERE
    keywordlink_ref_type = "product" AND product_deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = $this->getGateway()->getSql()->select();
$sql->from('product')->join('keywordlink', "keywordlink.ref_id" = "product.id", LEFT);
$sql->where->equalTo( 'keywordlink.column' = 'product.column');
$sql->where->equalTo('product.deleted', NULL);
$sql->group('product.product_id');
```

The column wasn't found because not pointing table in your query.The solution something like this,but for proper syntax of ZF2 query builder you should also check out this zend2 link: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html